# PHP row results without repeating

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, tags

I have a db with the following

```
----id---|-----name-----|-----owner----|----tags---------------|  
----1----|-----123------|------jc------|--van outside door-----|  
----2----|-----124------|------dw------|----van daz------------|  
----3----|-----125------|------jc------|--daz outside flower----|
```

what I am trying to do is echo out a list of all the words in the tag column without repeating the same word.

So far I have manage to echo

`van outside doorvan dazdaz outside flower` Notice repeating words and no space between rows.

I also would like the results to be url links `?t=$tag`

This is for the purpose of sorting photos.
Should I change the separator in the tag column to `,` as in `daz,indoor,flower`.

Heres my code

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos";
  $filterresult = mysql_query($sql);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filterresult))
      {
          $id = $row['id-name'];
          $name = $row['name'];
          $owner = $row['owner'];
          $tags = $row['tags'];

          $filterdir = "photos/$owner/index_files/vlb_thumbnails1/";
          $filterdir2 = "photos/$owner/index_files/vlb_images1/";

          echo "<a href=\"photoview102.php?t=$tags\">$tags</a>";

      }
```

ok heres the new code (thank you for your help so far)

```
$tags = array();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos";
  $filterresult = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filterresult))
      {
          $id = $row['id-name'];
          $name = $row['name'];
          $owner = $row['owner'];

          $tags = array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $tags));

          $filterdir = "photos/$owner/index_files/vlb_thumbnails1/";
          $filterdir2 = "photos/$owner/index_files/vlb_images1/";


      }


$tags = array_unique($tags);

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
echo "<a href=\"photoviewer102.php?t=$tag\">$tag</a>";
}
```

Comment: Please add your PHP code

Comment: `Please help its driving my wife mad as im spending too long sorting out our wedding photos!!` -- we can't really help you with that. Code. We need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done via [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array). You could store the tags inside an array and before putting it in check for its existence.

```
$tags = array();
//iterate over your rows+tags
    if (!in_array($current_tag, $tags))
        $tags[] = $current_tag;
```

Comment: I have tried this and it output "array array array" What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After you have a string of tags, do (untested)

```
// $tags = 'van outside door van daz daz indoor flower';
$tags = implode(' ', array_unique(explode(' ', $tags)));
// $tags = 'van outside door daz indoor flower';
```

Docs for [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

**EDIT**

In your code you print all tags within a row as one line, but you want to remove duplicate tags which are space separated. I wonder what's your expected output. Is it like this? (with your database)

```
van outside door
daz
flower
```

or this?

```
van
outside
door
daz
flower
```

The former sounds awkward for me, so I would assume you would like the latter case.

To get array of tags in your code, assuming your tags are space-separated, I would suggest, in your loop, replace

```
$tags = $row['tags'];
```

to

```
$tags = array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $row['owner']));
```

Docs for [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). You will need to initialize the `$tags` first, before the loop, as `$tags = array()`

After the loop, do the magic of removing duplicates. No more explode because we did it inside the loop and already have the array. No more implode either because we are going to print it element for element, not as a string.

```
$tags = array_unique($tags);
```

And defer printing of the tags i.e. move

```
echo "<a href=\"photoview102.php?t=$tags\">$tags</a>";
```

to after the loop

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo "<a href=\"photoview102.php?t=$tag\">$tag</a>";
}
```

---

About separator issue, you don't have to, unless your tags contain spaces. In this case, you may want to use comma instead. However, this will prevent you from using comma inside the tags.

Notably, Wordpress do use comma to separate tags for user input, but are stored differently in the database.

Comment: This isnt working for me as each result is unique, per row. i did think i need to create an array first and then find unique words in that, but i cant work out how to create the array. The code below just outs the word array three times.

Comment: Firstly yes i just want a list of all tags as you guessed.I have tried your code and i am getting Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in .... referring to $tags = array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $tags));

Comment: erros hav changed to just one now..Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo "<a href=\"photoview102.php?t=$tag\">$tag</a>";
}

Comment: Careless. What about replacing `array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $tags))` with `array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $row['owner']))` ?

Comment: In addition, don't use `mysql` APIs as they are deprecated. Use `Mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: I tried array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $row['owner'])) which didnt make much sense to me as im trying to get the tags not the owner and it didnt work. So then i tried array_merge($tags, explode(' ', $row['tags'])) and bingo all is right with the world. Thanks so much i literally cound not have done it without you.

Comment: Quick quesion is there a way to arrange them alphabetically?

Comment: I have tried sort. I put.it after loop and before for each but it didn't work? is this the right place? I have tried in other places and nothing seems to do it. I either gat the same results or none at all.

Comment: nevermind i was being a bit thick. I have done it now. Once again thank you.